# Error when deploy xap file

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

When I try to deploy .xap file to my phone. The error "You cannot install the application. You have reached the maximum number of applications being developed for the device can be installed on this development. Please uninstall a previous developer application. (I believe the current limit it 10 side-loaded apps at a time)" happened. Please help me solve the problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, as the message states. Uninstall one or more of the dev-apps you've previously installed on the device, then you'll be able to install new ones up to the maximum of 10.

Comment: Ngoc: Sounds like you're either deleting the wrong apps, or the phone's been corrupted. Maybe try resetting the phone back to factory settings and then starting from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

You can also raise a support ticket over at dev.windowsphone.com requesting an increase in the allowable app limit.

Comment: can you tell me how to  increase in the allowable app limit. Thanks

Comment: I did. Go to dev.windowsphone.com and raise a support ticket asking to raise the limit.